# How to convert GraphML to DOT format

Tags: graphviz, dot, graphml

I need to convert a GraphML file into a DOT format, but I am not familiar on how to perform the conversion.

Comment: What did you try so far?Did you google for e.g "GraphML to dot" ? Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24554061/converting-graphml-to-gv-or-dot-filecan help.

Comment: I've never used it, but here is a link: https://www.graphviz.org/pdf/graphml2gv.1.pdf

Answer (score -2):

#you should use export_graphviz

```
    from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
```

#to get dot data

```
    dot_data = export_graphviz(clasifier_name,out_file=None)
```